# java.lang.StackOverflowError and checkpointing on Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have some difficulties to execute this portion of code because i fall on the java.lang.StackOverflowError. After some research i find that it's cause by the nested structure i create in the loop which reach the stack size limit.

I read two option, the first is to increase the stack size limit, but we have to find the good balance beetween a tiny and a big for the size. How to know the good value ?

Another option is to checkpoint the RDD every Nth operation and be sure that it is persisted before being checkpointed.

Thus i try this piece of code, it seems that with enought value of stack size and checkpoiting even if i encounter an error, the computation will continue.

I will be glad to know if my understanding of the problem is good and if there are better options or if i can improve my code.

```
var ind1 = 0
while ( stop != 0 ) {

  val rdd1 = rddY.filter( x => { Vectors.sqdist(x._2,vector0) <= threshold }).cache

  val rdd2 = rdd1.map( x => (ind1.toString,x))

  rdd0 = sc.union(rdd0,rdd2).coalesce(numPart).cache
  if(ind1 % 20 == 19){
    rdd0.checkpoint()
  }
  rdd0.foreach(x=>{})

  rddY = rddY.subtract(rdd1).cache
  if(ind1 % 20 == 19){
    rddY.checkpoint()
  }
  stop = rddY.count().toInt

  if(stop != 0) { vector0 = rddY.first()._2 }
  ind1 += 1

  rdd1.unpersist()
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36258397/iterative-code-with-long-lineage-rdd-causes-stackoverflow-error-in-apache-spark/36258905#36258905, you might need to place checkpoint calls before actions on RDDs (e.g.`rdd0.foreach(x=>{})` and `stop = rddY.count().toInt`) for the checkpoint to take effect

Comment: @TzachZohar this seems like a valid answer to me. Don't you want to post it ?

Comment: @KyBe I see you edited the code according to my comment - did that solve the issue? It should work without a need to increase the stack size, I think.

Comment: It works like à charm. Thank you !